# Проблема с std::vector::insert()

Tags: c++, vector, stl, insert

Есть следующий код:

```cpp
static std::vector<const char*> vec = {"str1","str2","str3","str4"};
```

есть также

```cpp
static std::string tempstring;
```

При первом проходе(первый вызов функции);

я записываю в `tempstring`  значение одного из `vec`,например `vec[3]`, что равно `"str4"`.

и делаю

```cpp
vec.erase(iterator + 3);
```

Элемент откуда надо удаляется.

Значения vec следующие: `[0] = "str1",[1] = "str2",[2] = "str3";`

На следующем проходе (второй раз вызов функции)  я делаю следующее:

```cpp
vec.insert(iterator+3,tempstring.c_str());
```

В `vec` в данный момент значения получаются такими: `[0] = "str1",[1] = "str2",[2] = "str3",[3] = "str4"`.
То есть все как задумано.Но как только я присваиваю значение в  `tempstring`,например `vec[0]`,что равно `"str1"`.
То есть `tempstring = vec[0];`
Сразу же меняется и сам vec.

То есть после присваивания значения вектора в tempstring значения становятся следующими:
`[0] = "str1",[1] = "str2",[2] = "str3",[3] = "str1"`.

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: во первых вы второй раз пытаетесь удалять элемент, не принадлежащий вектору, а что самое главное:  После операции удаления  итератор вектора становится недействительным, и все ваши действия приводят к неопределенному поведению  всей программы...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan давайте все же предпологать, что `iterator` есть ничто иное как `vec.begin()` тогда никакого неопределённого поведения не будет - в вопросе совершенно другая проблема..

Comment: @ampawd, если вы так хотите предпологать, то  в векторе  из 4 _ х элементов, как вы собираетесь 2 раза удалять  vec.begin() + 3 и иметь определенное поведение?  Я не собираюсь возрожать(вам лучше знать что предпологать), но в таком случаи почему вы не говорите какая же проблема в вопросе? О какой другой проблеме речь?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan объясните пожалуйста, где вы вопросе умудрились найти 2 раза удаление ?? Там же всего один вызов `erase`

Comment: @ampawd,, ну не знаю, или я стал не внимательным, или ТС  запутал со своими "хорошими" объяснениями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tempstring.c_str()` возвращает указатель не на новою строку, а на буфер `tempstring` в котором храниться строка, следовательно вы добавляете в вектор указатель на буфер `tempstring`. Если вдруг вы зададите `tempstring` строку побольше и произойдёт перевыделение буфера, то обращение к `vec[3]` будет являться неопределённым поведением, т.к. память по данному указателю уже будет недействительна. Решением будет использовать `vector<const string>`

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы используете метод [vector::insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) вы передаёте ссылку на переменную которую требуется добавить.

> void insert (iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val);

Метод insert не копирует данные из вашей строки в новую переменную, а вставляет ссылку от неё, как видно на снимке экрана:

[image: Состояние вектора после добавления строки.]

Следовательно после изменения строки изменится и значение соответствующего элемента в векторе.

Comment: В качестве замечания - вы путаете термтны "указатель" и "ссылка". В C++ это существенно разные вещи

Comment: В метод передаётся ссылка, а в сам вектор записывается указатель? Просто я и вправду путаюсь в них)

Comment: Тот метод, что вы привели как раз таки копирует, но в данном случае он скопирует значение указателя, т.к. в вопросе вектор указателей. А то, что вы подчеркнули - это адрес буфера tempstring, одинаковые они потому что `tempstring.c_str()` и возвращает указатель на буфер строки

Comment: Понял, спасибо)